# Node.js mysql2 как получить данные извне из полученной строки из таблицы

Tags: mysql, node.js, вконтакте

Есть код - получение строки из таблицы.
Внутри этого метода всё хорошо получается и выводит отдельное значение, а извне такое не работает. Как получать данные извне?

Использую vk-io и mysql2

Код:

```js
mysql.getUser = async(ID) => {
    let user_nick = (await vk.api.users.get({ user_ids: ID }))[0].first_name
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE vkid=${ID}`,
    function(err, results, fields){
        if(err) return console.log(err.message)
        const users = results;
        if(results.length < 1) {
            con.query(`INSERT INTO users (nick, vkid) VALUES ('${user_nick}', '${ID}')`,
            function(err, result){
                if(err) return console.log(err.message)
                console.log(users[0].nick)
            })
        } else {
            console.log(users[0].vkid + ` айди`)
        }

        return console.log(users[0].coins)
    })
}

console.log(mysql.getUser(444355266))
```

P.s. выдаёт Promise { <.pending> } в консоль

Comment: @MoloF async/await нужно написать перед функциями или в строчках, в которых вызывается метод **mysql.getUser**?

Comment: @iBuseWinner перед `con.query`, например `const [rows,fields] = await con.query()` [есть примеры](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)